# Finding all harmonic functions on $n$-torus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $\mathbb{T}^n:=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^n$ be the $n$-torus.

Then, I am trying to find all solutions of the equation $\Delta f =0$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$.

However, I cannot really see how to find "ALL" of them..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: To start, write down one example $f$ that is not constant.